# How to keep products in shopping cart for non registered clients - Magento

Tags: php, magento, cart

I am trying for some time to change the magento functionality to keep products in shopping cart for non registered clients. The products are disappearing after couple of hours from the shopping cart.

If the client is registered then the products are there.

I am working on Magento 1.7 and I am trying to figure this out for some time. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is this with the Persistent Cart feature turned on?

Comment: Yes. The persistent shopping cart is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the cookie lifetime in system > configuration > web > cookie management.

===EDIT===

The problem can also come from the session_lifetime defined by php_ini.

Comment: I've already did that. The value is 31536000 and the path is /. This is not working

Comment: use persistence checkout functionality

Comment: Persistent checkout is already there and is working very good for registered clients. The setup is based on magento website tutorial

Comment: can you check the cookie lifetime on your browser and the session lifetime on your server ?

Comment: Cookie lifetime is correct. I've already looked on cookie lifetime with a cookie reader for browser. If you have some tool in mind please let me know

Comment: check you php.ini for cookie lifetime

Comment: I've change the value into 31536000 and restart apache. I've add a product into the shopping cart and this morning was not there anymore. So after ~ 12 hours is gone.

Comment: i am sorry, i was meaning session_lifetime... is it the same ? In that case, I am affraid I cannot help you more.

Comment: Is working Christophe Ferreboeuf. Update the response and I will mark it as valid. Thank you!